# Modeling custom relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, relationship

I would like to know which is the best way to generate this kind of relationship:

I have two models: an Answer and an Article.

An Answer is defined as follows:

```
**Answer**
 - content:text
 - link:string
```

I would like to create an Article as follows

```
**Article**
 - title:string
 - what:Answer
 - when:Answer
 - how:Answer
 - why:Answer
```

Which is the best way to create the Article model?

I know an Article `has_many` Answers and an Answer `belongs_to` an Article but I do not know how to achieve this relationship or how to limit the number of answers of the Article to four (what, when how, why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create an Answer model:

```
**Answer**
  - content:text
  - link:string
  - question_type:string
```

`question_type` would be 'what', 'when', 'who' or 'why'. And an Article model:

```
**Article**
  - title:string
```

You can then set up your relationships like so:

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

Finally, you could write a custom validator to ensure that articles only get assigned 1x each question type. The validator would look something like:

**article.rb**

```
validate :question_type_validator

def question_type_validator
  question_types = answers.all.map(&:question_type)
  question_types.each do |question_type|
    if question_types.count(question_type) > 1
      errors.add(:question_type, "Must only have one of each, what, when, who, why.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok I really like this approach. I was having problems modeling this relationship because I kept thinking on a one - to - one relationship, but I think a one to many is a better approach. Thank you!